# How many cells with same color in raster map

Tags: raster

I'd like to see how many cells have the same color based on my classification. An example is shown here:
You can see the count figure under the raster map.

[image: count figure]

Answer (score 0):

which program are you using? qgis, arcMap?
If you have an attribute table that would be the simplest way with the field calculator tool.

Comment: Arcmap, I convert my point data to 0.25-0.25 resolution gridcell raster. Then I classified all data into 4 data range such as 1-3, 4-8. Each color in raster represents one number range. I want that count of color.

Comment: Build a raster attribute table https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m2000000 if your classifications are integer, if not use Reclassify to make integer values, in this table will be the cell values and the count of cells with that value. BTW this isn't an answer but I can see you don't have enough reputation to post a comment.. if you edit your answer to include the mentioned tool and a screen shot of the RAT it would be acceptable as an answer which should come close to earning enough rep to post comments.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it with your answer, Michael.

Comment: As you have an answer to your question can you please answer it with a screen shot of your attribute table. I don't have any integer rasters to answer properly myself.